# Is there a way to nest Twitter Bootstrap modals?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a way to identify a 2nd modal as being a child of the first, eg:

```
.modal .modal {
   /*change some styles to make nested modal look different*/
}
```

Even though I place the HTML of the 2nd modal within that of the first, when the Browser loads Bootstrap compiles them to sit independently outside of the `#wrapper`.

Eg, I set it up as this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But on browser load I get this:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

So my css (`.modal .modal`) deosnt work.

Would anyone know how I can identify a child modal?

(I know I can put IDs on them, but as these modals are shared on other pages and appear as stand alone [non-nested] modals, styling the ID directly would not work).

Answer (score 0):

You can open a modal via a modal. That should solve your issue :)

Comment: Yes you can,  but they still appear as independent modals. You can only put the `data-toggle="modal"`tag within a modal, but not the actual modal itself

Answer (score 0):

I found a not-so-elegant way to do this with JQuery, but am open to better suggestions.

```
    $(".modal [data-toggle='modal']").each(function( index ) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var modalref = $(this).attr('data-target');
            $(modalref).addClass('child-modal');
        });
    });
   $('.modal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click(function() {
        $('.modal').removeClass('child-modal');
   });
```